# WebStorm - revert syntax highlighting colour to an older version

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I had been using WebStorm 2018.2 for years and have recently updated to 2020.2.

How can I change the colour scheme back to 2018.2. For instance, `console` / `process` was white, now purple, `require` was yellow, now white.

**Update**

[image]

[image]

Here you can see the difference of `require` statement, how can I change it back to yellow?

Comment: For reference purposes: the same on WebStorm Forums https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010025160-Webstorm-revert-syntax-highlighting-colour-to-an-older-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be changed in `File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | JavaScript > Global function`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. `Global variable` works for `console`, `process`, however `Global function` doesn't work for `require`.

Comment: @TriNguyen Try this to find out what styles are in use: 1) place caret on such element (e.g. `require` in your case) 2) Invoke `Help | Find Action...` 3) Type `jump to` there -- you need to locate and invoke `Jump to Colors and Fonts` entry. 4) Once invoked, a popup will appear that lists all styles that can affect the element under caret -- you can use to change the colors (if not possible to change it right there then at very least you will know what style to look for)

Comment: Hi @LazyOne, thank you for your answer, sorry for the late reply. Following your steps points out that `require` is categorised as a local variable in Javascript. There's no point changing that cause that would make lots of variables turn yellow. Is there any way I can update the colour for a particular variable?

Comment: @TriNguyen *"Is there any way I can update the colour for a particular variable"* AFAIK -- no. Maybe one day: watch these and linked tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25271

Comment: @Oksana Thank you, got the global variable working, marked your answer as accepted